# Counting inversions

Tags: scala, sorting

I'm trying to implement an inversion counting routine in Scala in a functional way (I don't want to port Java solution) but have real troubles with it. The sorting routine works fine but adding the code to count inversions leads to stack overflow error. Here's the code in question:

```
  object FuncSort
   def streamMerge(l: Stream[Int], r: Stream[Int]) : Stream[Int] = {
    (l, r) match {
      case (x#::xs, Empty) => l
      case (Empty, y#::ys) => r
      case (x#::xs, y#::ys) => if(x < y) x#::streamMerge(xs, r) else y#::streamMerge(l, ys)
    }
  }

  // This function works albeit slow
  def streamSort(xs: Stream[Int]) : Stream[Int] = {
    if(xs.lengthCompare(1) <= 0) xs
    else {
      val m = xs.length / 2
      val (l, r) = xs.splitAt(m)
      streamMerge(streamSort(l), streamSort(r))
    }
  }

  // This one fails with StackOverflowError
  def mergeAndCount(l: Stream[Int], r: Stream[Int]) : (Long, Stream[Int]) = {
    (l, r) match {
      case (x#::xs, Empty) => (0, l)
      case (Empty, y#::ys) => (0, r)
      case (x#::xs, y#::ys) => if(x < y) {
        lazy val (i, s) = mergeAndCount(xs, r)
        (i, x#::s)
      } else {
        lazy val (i, s) = mergeAndCount(l, ys)
        (i + l.length, y#::s)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive calls to `mergeAndCount` are not in tail position, so the Scala compiler can not use tail optimisation and the stack grows till it overflows its alloted space.  The `lazy` modifier in `lazy val (i, s)` is doing you no good at all, by the way.

Scala can only do tail optimisation if the recursive call to `mergeAndCount` is the last expression to be called *and even then* only if the value returned is not modified in anyway but simply passed straight back, all the way to the first recursive call to `mergeAndCount`.

To fix this, you could add a local helper function inside `mergeAndCount`, which takes as parameters not only the two streams but also the state you need to carry forward.  It would look something like this..

```
def mergeAndCount(left: Stream[Int], right: Stream[Int]) = {
  def mac(l: Stream[Int], r: Stream[Int], m: Stream[Int], count: Long): (Long, Stream[Int]) = (l, r) match {
    case (x #:: xs, Empty) => (count, merge append l)
    case (Empty, y #:: ys) => (count, merge append r)
    case (x #:: xs, y #:: ys) if x < y => mac(xs, r, x #:: m, count + 1)
    case (x #:: xs, y #:: ys) => mac(l, ys, y #:: m, count + 1)
  }
  mac(left, right, Stream.empty, 0)
}
```

I may not have understood how the count is supposed to work, but I think the general idea is clear.  Note how I split your final case statement into two by turning the `if` condition into a guard - it's tidier, I think.  Note also that if an entire function is one big pattern match, you don't have to wrap the match in braces.

To be fair, nothing about

```
streamMerge(streamSort(l), streamSort(r))
```

is in tail position either, but because all 3 functions return only a stream, you get away with it.

Comment: Then how does the `streamMerge` method work with large streams? It's not tail-recursive.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I'm asking about. Inversion counter introduces strict evaluation into sorting routine so I'm looking for a way to lazily evaluate it.

Comment: @synapse Streams use **thunks** and lazy evaluation to return as quickly as possible.  `StreamMerge` is *mathematically* recursive but it isn't *actually* recursive in the generated code; there is only ever one call to `StreamMerge` happening at once.

Comment: Oop, edited my comment so things are out of sequence.  @synapse, your original question talks about the stack overflow problem and nothing else - the code comments happen to mention the slow performance of the sort, but you only made that the focus of your question in the comment you just made here.

Comment: What makes StreamSort slow is the calls to `lengthCompare` and `length`, because they force realisation of the entire stream.  There are ways to work around this.  Don't have time to go into them now but can find some time tonight.

Comment: Is it because the second argument to `#::` operator is lazily evaluated? (Changing `Stream` to `List` results in stack overflow) How can I do the same with numbers?

Comment: Yes, the lazy evaluation is the key.  What do you mean by "How can I do the same with numbers?"? Anything that can be expressed as a recursive function can be turned into a stream.

Comment: it looks like the question is out of scope of this substack. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18980612/porting-haskell-inversion-counter-to-scala